# How to change the hostname "localhost" in Windows OS?

Tags: servlets, browser, localhost, system, host

I am trying to change the hostname from "**localhost**" to "**systemhost**" (user-defined names).

I was actually running a servlet program where I suddenly got a question, if it is possible to change the hostname from *localhost (default)* to *systemhost (user-defined)*

What I have done so far:

- Searched on the google but I get irrelevant answers.
- Changed the `server.xml` file content from *localhost* to *systemhost* as I was running servlet program so I thought that this change can work along.

[image]

- Navigated to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` and changed the *hosts* file. Replaced the word localhost to systemhost.

[image]

After doing all these no success. I wonder, if it is really possible to change?

---

Any help or suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Your hosts file has the line commented out so it won't mean anything. Uncomment it

Comment: Hi rbashish, off topic, I notice you're trying your hand at the editing system, but the two edits I saw had problems (I just had to reject one because it basically introduced even *more* errors into the question). Make sure you check your edits closely before suggesting them, and check out our guidelines, e.g. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11474/what-is-the-etiquette-for-modifying-posts Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uncomment that line by removing `#`.
it should be:

```
127.0.0.1 systemhost
::1 systemhost
```